# RapidClipse X + 11 deployment generates a "war-file" without any index-file inside

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, rapidclipse

I am interested in working with rapidclipse and I tried it out a little.
I installed rapidclipse on win10 pro.
Everything works fine, and the internal preview from rapidclipse works shows the expected result.

But when I generate a war-file and deploy it to Tomcat, Tomcat shows an error: "resource not found".
I found out that there were no index files in the deployed folder from Tomcat.
After creating an index file manually, the error disappeared from Tomcat.

At last I found out, there is no index-file inside the war-archive.

The index-file in the generated war-archive by rapidclipse is always missing.

I guess that it is a configuration problem of rapidclipse.

Is there anybody there who can help me?

**What i've tried:**

- I updated maven as is it described in the tutorial and checked all possible configurations in the properties from rapidclipse.
- I used different Tomcat versions (9,10,11), and also a jetty server for deploying.
- I installed rapidclipse in different versions (10,11) on different machines (4 or 5 pcs)

Comment: Not an answer, but I used RC11 on Linux and I had the same problem. 
Running in RC/Eclipse development environment works fine, But deployment on other tomcat by a generated war file did not work.

Answer (score 1):

In the Develop Perspective select your RapidClipse Project, then right click on it to open the context menu. Click on 'Run As' then 'Maven build...'. In the dialog enter the following in the field 'goals':

clean package -Pproduction

Then press 'Run'. At the end a .war-File has been created in your /target folder of the RapidClipse Project which contains everything to run this .war-File on another machine running.

If you only have choosed 'clean package' the .war-File does not contain all necessary files to run on another machine.